# Design that outperforms buck converter

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck, efficiency

[image]

[image]

Above is quoted from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-a-pwm-signal-into-an-analog-voltage/). I was just shocked to find out that the first image provides a much more efficient and simpler way to step down a voltage instead of using a buck converter circuit (second image).

The first image almost provides a 98% step-down voltage efficiency and is so simple. If this is so, why is this design not used in chargers and why are buck converters used so widely?

new one
[image: pmoss]

Comment: A buck converter requires a diode to enable current flow when the pulse switches off, so I doubt your efficiency numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first *is* a buck converter. Notice the **Pulse** source. The way you get that in the article they describe is through a micro-controller pin. How does that pin work? Well....it's a transistor.

The top image is a buck converter with the transistor hidden in a micro-controller. The downside of it is that micro-controller pins don't generally have a high current capability because their transistors are small/of thin widths.

Usually, to create a buck converter that can source significant current, you'll use a micro-controller or a dedicated buck driver that will create the PWM you're after to drive high-current transistors.

To summarize, the first is a buck converter, it's just  small one. For most applications, we want more power/current so we just use that to drive larger transistors that run the buck converter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. May I ask why the need for synchronous PWM switching (As shown above, PWM driver and inverted PWM driver) when we can just ignore them and use the first design for simplicity ? :)

Comment: @catherinetan Sure. The simplest Buck design isn't synchronous high-side and low-side switching, it's simply a high-side switch; replace the low side with a Diode, but that's slightly less efficient because you have a diode forward voltage drop you can't get rid of.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#/media/File:Buck_operating.svg

Comment: Also note that internal to the micro-controller pin that gives you the **Pulse** supply are two transistors, one to drive it high and one to pull it low. So your first is not all that much simpler internally. It's just hidden more.

Comment: Right, I see it now haha. Thank you :)

Comment: @catherinetan Moreover, circuit 1 is "open loop"... it will only work optimally with specific values of L, C, R and f.   Circuit 2 looks to be from an IC datasheet, presumably there would be feedback internally (i.e. "closed loop") that's not drawn which would tweak the pulse width as necessary to maintain a decently stable output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the simpler buck converter schematic at the top (all your schematics are buck converters) is not favored over more complex synchronous designs is because, put simply, it is vastly inferior in terms of cost, size, efficiency, and capability.

The lion's share of any switching converter's losses are lost entirely in the switching element. In other words, the MOSFET in your lower schematic.

Your top schematic has simply omitted the part of a buck converter that is responsible for most of the losses.  So of course it seems more efficient.  But this is impossible in practice, as there must be some sort of switch upstream that is pulsing the current in the first place. It will dissipate heat when doing this, and you've at best obfuscated rather an actually reduced the true losses of your switching converter.

And even then, I doubt your first simulation is of anything physical.  Did you give the capacitor realistic ESR?  Try 5mΩ if using a larger sized ceramic.  And the inductor you're using is huge and expensive.  22mH is **a lot** of inductance and will require a pretty hefty volume of magnetic core material to maintain that inductance any appreciable current.  I checked digikey and a similar inductor (27mH vs 22mH) could do no more than 1.6A (your peak current must be below that.  Average current will be even less) and cost $14.  It is also large and heavy.

You could buy 8 (yes, eight!) more capable buck converters (of albeit dubious quality, but they still generally work) from a variety of sources for the same cost as that inductor.

You have also eliminated the diode which means that your buck converter has a minimum load for it to output DC.  This is heavily dependent on inductor size - you've used such a large and impractical inductor that it has hid this problem somewhat, but if you were to use a smaller one, you'll see what I mean.  The voltage ripple is DC as long as the average inductor current plus the ripple current always stays flowing in the expected direction.  The moment your load becomes light enough that the current through the inductor will actually reach zero, it stops being DC.

The voltage will go negative, and you now have AC on the output. Any buck converter will enter this mode where current will stop flowing through the inductor entirely if the load is small enough. This is better known as **discontinuous mode**. Your simulations only show you **continuous mode**. If you plan to only power resistive loads or other things that don't care about polarity or DC vs AC, then this is no problem.

But if you actually want a DC/DC converter, then omitting the diode is going to potentially destroy whatever it is you are powering with it. Even if the load is constant and above the minimum, the moment it is turned off for any reason can result in a large pulse of negative voltage from the inductor (**back emf**) that is almost equal to your normal output voltage, but negative/opposite polarity. Anything that expects DC will not be too keen on this and a large number of devices will simply be destroyed when this event occurs. Or damaged slightly, but this will happen every single time the converter is turned off. You won't see this until you use a more reasonable inductor size, like 100µH (which is still quite large for a buck converter).  But if it a try with two orders of magnitude less inductance (which would still be kind of expensive considering how cheap these can be made) and you'll see what I mean about that negative spike.  Lower the pulse count so you can watch it turn off.

Finally, the example you gave is hardly more complicated. It adds back 1 component: the diode. The only difference is instead of using an actual diode which can be a heavy source of losses due to the forward voltage drop (especially at higher currents), they use a second MOSFET to act as a switch and rather than blocking the reverse current flow, it simply goes open circuit to do the same.  MOSFETs are resistive, and so their losses can be potentially much less than a diode (since the voltage drop across the MOSFET is determined by the current and Rds_ON resistance, rather than being a fixed 0.6V or what have you for a Schottky diode.)

Conveniently, the PWM waveform for the second switch is identical to the PWM waveform through the high side switch, but inverted. There needs to be a little delay added between each transition so both the high and low side MOSFETs aren't ever turned on at the same time.  Otherwise it will cause 'shoot through'.

Synchronous buck converters are the best buck converter out there. They can achieve very high efficiencies, especially multiphase ones. Their losses are no different than your design once the MOSFET is added back in. Only, if you actually want it to only output DC, you need that diode, and this is where synchronous buck converters beat out the rest.